# PHP:I want to run a function every 30sec's without using a for loop

Tags: php

php has header('refresh:30')

When i'm getting data from a form via post,the array resets on refresh(when i use header-refresh)

I was looking for a setTimeOut(in javascript) sorta tool in php or a way to persist a variable got from the user(form data) even after a refresh.

-- Php Beginner

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> ...or a way to persist a variable got from the user(form data) even after a refresh.

Try using $_SESSION to keep certain variables. This will allow the variables to be kept even after navigating away to another page. Keep in mind that you must start the session with `session_start()` before using sessions.

http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.session.php

As to the rest of your question, I'm not exactly sure what you're asking... >_>

Comment: the problem is : i have to take in data from one frame and use it in another.The 2nd frame has to refresh every 30sec's or so with the data given in the 1st frame.But,on using header-refresh,i'm losing the data send via post(which is getting reset).So,i want to refresh the 2nd frame with the data sent via post from the 1st frame  ---- Using any php tool( without for loop)

Comment: So, you have two frames, 1 with a form and one with the results. When you submit the form, the results show up, but they go away once refreshed, correct? You can still use $_SESSION data here -- when a form is submitted, add the values to a session variable and then use those variable in the results. When the page refreshes again, the session data will still be there.

Comment: Also, this seems like it would be better suited via AJAX (easily done via jQuery); then again, I don't exactly know your implementation or what you're trying to achieve, so I shouldn't really comment on why you want it done this way ;)

Answer (score 0):

You should use

`window.onload = setInterval("function_to_refresh_data()",3000) //3000 is interval in milliseconds`

Use Ajax response in a div so that only that div refreshes , otherwise the whole page will be refreshed .

Comment: i was looking for a php tool.